# My model used to work so fine, but now only its bones move, not the mesh itself with it!

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, bones

Here's a image to show u what actually my problem is:
[image: You can see how the bone moves out of the arm.]
Didn't change any settings, except the textures.
I got the same model in another blend file that works so pretty fine but this one not! i really really need this to work!

Do ya know any way on how to fix it folks? :(

Comment: Hello, we can't see any image

Comment: hhh.. damn my internet connection, it's like i'm in a desert. I'm gonna fix that now

Comment: it's pretty incomprehensible, maybe pack the image and share your file

Comment: Dude i'm telling what the problem is, actually i'd recorded a clip of that to show everything i mean, but i couldn't share or upload it somewhere, if ya want, i might be able send it to ur Email. But the whole case: is that when i switch to the posr mode, and try to move a bone assigned to my model, it moves but the mesh of the model doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know why but pretty much restarting the whole system made it work :/
it's done.